# Type Error: Member "userAddress" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct wavePortal.Payment storage ref[] storage ref

Tags: solidity, alchemy

THE CODE:

```
    //SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity >= 0.8.0 < 0.9.0;
    import "hardhat/console.sol";
    contract wavePortal {
struct Payment {
    address userAddress;
    uint noOfWave;
}

uint length;
uint totWaves;
uint count = 1;
mapping(address => Payment[]) maxwave;
mapping(address => uint) individualCount;

constructor() {
    console.log("Welcome to ETH dApp");
}

function wave() public {
    totWaves++;
    console.log("we got a wave from %s", msg.sender);
}

function Paymentfn() public 
    
{

    Payment[] storage payment = maxwave[msg.sender];
    address[] memory addresses = new address[](maxwave[msg.sender].length);
    uint[] memory noOfWaves = new uint[](maxwave[msg.sender].length);

    uint numberOfWaves = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < maxwave[msg.sender].length; i++) {
        addresses[numberOfWaves] = [msg.sender][i];
        numberOfWaves++;
    }
    length = addresses.length;
    for(uint i=0;i<addresses.length;i++){
        if(addresses[i]==msg.sender){
        payment.push(
            Payment({
                userAddress:addresses[i],
                noOfWave: individualCount[msg.sender]++
            })
         );
        }
        else{
        payment.push(
            Payment({
                userAddress: msg.sender,
                noOfWave: individualCount[msg.sender]++
            })
        );
        }
    }           

    maxwave[msg.sender] = payment;

}

function getPayment() public view returns (address[] memory, uint[] memory){
    for(uint i=0;i<length;i++){
        return (maxwave[msg.sender].userAddress, maxwave[msg.sender].noOfWave);
    }
}

function getTotWaves() public view returns (uint) {
    console.log("we have a %d waves", totWaves);
    return totWaves;
}
```

}

This code is to wave the hand and count the total number of waves. I added a new feature which includes all the addresses which waved the hands and also number of times it waved.

But i am facing error while returning the structure[in getPayment() function] saying that userAddress is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way to access the `userAddress` field of an element in the `maxwave` mapping:

```
maxwave[msg.sender][i].userAddress
```

And there are an important changes todo with the `getPayment()` function:

```
function getPayment() public view returns (address[] memory, uint[] memory){
    address[] memory addresses = new address[](maxwave[msg.sender].length);
    uint[] memory noOfWaves = new uint[](maxwave[msg.sender].length);
    for(uint i=0;i<maxwave[msg.sender].length;i++){
        addresses[i] = maxwave[msg.sender][i].userAddress;
        noOfWaves[i] = maxwave[msg.sender][i].noOfWave;
    }
    return (addresses, noOfWaves);
}
```